# How to get the Instagram profile info?

Tags: api, instagram

i'd like to know on how to get instagrams profile info ( avatar and followers count) to display on request.

You can see the script in action here: http://followers10k.club/

Do i need to access IG api?

Or it can be made with some sort of scrapping ?

Thank you very much i advance!

Answer (score 0):

I've found script that's responsible for displaying IG username with follower info:

```
 <?php                                  
                    $username = $_GET['username'];
                    $url = "https://www.instagram.com/" . $username;                                   
                    $data = @file_get_contents($url);
                    preg_match('/\"followed_by\"\:\s?\{\"count\"\:\s?([0-9]+)/',$data,$followed_by);
                    preg_match('/\"follows\"\:\s?\{\"count\"\:\s?([0-9]+)/',$data,$following);
                    preg_match('/\"full_name"\:\s?\"([a-zA-Z ]+)/',$data,$full_name);
                    preg_match('/\"profile_pic_url"\:\s?\"((http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)(.*?)")/',$data,$profile_pic);                  
                if ($data === false) { ?>
```

My problem now is: when anyone enters a real instagram username my website doesn't recognize it and says there is an error & enter a valid username.